# Checking Error: request entity too large expressjs nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting a lot of request entity too large in my expressjs app (version 3.21)

```
6|server  | 2022-12-13 02:58 +00:00: Error: request entity too large
6|server  |     at readStream (/root/www/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:196:17)
6|server  |     at getRawBody (/root/www/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12)
6|server  |     at read (/root/www/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:68:3)
6|server  |     at jsonParser (/root/www/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:121:5)
6|server  |     at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:60:5)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at Object.compression [as handle] (/root/www/node_modules/connect/node_modules/compression/index.js:205:5)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at Object.handle (/root/www/node_modules/cloudflare-express/index.js:19:4)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:176:9)
6|server  |     at cors (/root/www/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
6|server  |     at /root/www/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
6|server  |     at origin (/root/www/server.js:199:16)
6|server  |     at /root/www/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
6|server  |     at optionsCallback (/root/www/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
6|server  |     at Object.corsMiddleware [as handle] (/root/www/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at Object.handle (/root/www/server.js:185:7)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/root/www/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at Object.query [as handle] (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:43:5)
6|server  |     at next (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
6|server  |     at Function.app.handle (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:182:3)
6|server  |     at Server.app (/root/www/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:67:37)
6|server  |     at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
6|server  |     at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/io/build/main/metrics/httpMetrics.js:166:33)
6|server  |     at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:998:12)
6|server  |     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
```

I have my expressjs set to 200kb limit.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '200kb'}));
```

How do I check what's being sent to my server that's passed the limit? I'm getting a TON of these messages in my logs, multiple a second, concerned that someone's trying to DDOS me or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the req post body with the buffer from request,
place this code block before the Bodyparser middleware:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.rawData = '';
  req.setEncoding('utf-8');

  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    req.rawData += chunk;
  });

  req.on('end', () => {
    console.log(req.rawData);
    next();
  });
});

app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '200kb'}));
```

Comment: Will this only show me the requests that are too large or all requests?